# Pass param for SSRS report via URL on Power BI server

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

We have new Power BI server that runs both Power BI and SSRS reports. I want to pass param values to the SSRS report via URL.
There are plenty of examples on web but all I've found were examples how to do that for the old servers, were URL structure was different.
The URL to my report is:
http://localhost/powerbi_reports_dev/report/SSRS%20Reports/Workflow/Report1

I want to pass `par=1` (where `par` is the name of parameter) to that report. How to do that?